# Difference: Between textbox = "" and Null

Tags: .net

What is the difference between

```
TextBox1.Text = null;
```

and

```
TextBox1.Text = "";
```

both clears or nullifies the textbox, but is there any particular difference?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are refering to **WinForms**, this is an excerpt from ILSpy of `System.Windows.Forms.Control`:

```
public virtual string Text
{
    get
    {
        // ...
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = "";
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

So as you can see, both passing `null` and `string.Empty` results in assigning `string.Empty` to the control.

If you are refering to ASP.NET (**WebForms**), the same applies, as you can see from this excerpt of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`:

```
public virtual string Text
{
    get
    {
        string text = (string)this.ViewState["Text"];
        if (text != null)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["Text"] = value;
    }
}
```

Here, in the `get` part, it returns `string.Empty` for a `null` value, too.

**My conclusion** would be that there is *no practical* difference for your daily use of the `TextBox` control.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to ASP.NET Web Forms:

`""` is an actual string, which has a length of 0.

`null`, means that the string variable points to nothing. And therefore will not produce a value.

When the TextBox is rendered into HTML, there will be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox1.Text is property available in TextBox class, where in setter null check is added before assigning the value. Some thing simpler to below code.

```
string txt= string.Empty;



 public string Text
    {
        get {
            return txt;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                txt = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                txt = value;
            }
        }
    }
```